# How do I get past 'Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported' error when publishing a .NET project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Thanks for looking.

## Background

I am working on a solution in VS2012 that has been publishing (file system) to it's destination folder with no problem whatsoever for several months.

The solution builds successfully and runs in localhost successfully.

## Problem

Today, I attempted to publish the solution and got this error:

`Error  1   Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported.   0   0  API`

As you can see, the error doesn't even point to a line number.

I have tried cleaning, rebuilding, deleting everything in the destination folder, closing and then restarting Visual Studio, and so on.

Still, the problem remains.  Has anyone else seen this or know the cause & solution?

## The last few lines from the Output window:

```
4>ExcludeFilesByExtension
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1443,5): Error : Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported.
4>
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure of the cause of this problem, but the solution was for me to go into source control and get a version of the `.csproj` that was created on my previous check in (a day ago).  That did the trick.

If you aren't using source control (shame!) then just make a copy of your current .csproj for safekeeping then remove it from the project folder, then create a new project of the same type (e.g. MVC Internet Application) in a different location.  After that, you can copy the new .csproj, paste it in your project and rename it (to have the same name as the old .csproj that you made a copy of).

Hope this saves someone else the frustration.

Answer (score 1):

You have some missing files in your project , look for the items and delete any item with yellow rectangle, even if it is only image file, if the item exists in the project tree it doesn't mean it is exists on file system .

Comment: Thanks, but I just double checked and don't see anything that is missing.  It is an API project only and just has a few files.  Thanks again.

Comment: Have you checked permission on destination folder ?

Comment: No.  I do suppose that could have changed.  I will check that.  It seems that I would get a different error though. . .

Comment: Permissions are okay.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check the other projects. Set all files which are also content files in your main project to "Build Action: none".

In my case I seperated features to multiple projects which share the same physical folder.
I had the web.config shared between them (due to Nuget changes this comes aoutomatically into your project).

After I set this and just have one time in my main project the web.config set to "Build Action: content" this works.

I asume this could also happen with all other files with the same name and location...